# Disable jquery star plugin after user rate

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have implemented jquery star rating. When user add its rate I save it to database and disable star rating.
But after disabling if user click on star again it again call js function and try to save score to database.

```
<input name="rating" type="radio" class="star" value="3" />
...
$('.star').click(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Rate", "Rating")',
                data: $("#rate").serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    alert('Your rating has been recorded');   
                    $('.star').rating('disable', true);
                },
                error: function(response) {
                alert('There was an error.');
              }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could unbind the click event (using `off()`) after the ajax call

```
 $('.star').click(function(event) {
     var $this = $(this);
     ...
     success: function(response) {
         alert('Your rating has been recorded');   
         $this.off('click');
     },

 });
```

I suppose you may have several `.star` elements so you should unbind the handler attached on the clicked link only.

Another simpler possibility is to bind the handler using `.one()`, like so

```
 $('.star').one('click', function(event) {
     var $this = $(this);
     ...
     success: function(response) {
         alert('Your rating has been recorded');   

     },

 });
```

this will allow one click event only for each different `.star` element

Anyway, I strongly suggest you to make this kind of check also on server side. Dont rely on client side for actions that may alter data on the server

Comment: I will :) Thanks I didn't know about '.one'